# Unable to run app on xcode 15 beta 5 using simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I installed Xcode 15 beta 5, but cannot get default generated app to run on any simulator. The error is:

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: The system shell (SpringBoard:3638) probably crashed.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-08-02 17:35:15 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    NSLocalizedFailure = "The request to open \"com.javajoe.BasicApp\" failed.";
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}

System Information

macOS Version 13.5 (Build 22G74)
Xcode 15.0 (22237.2) (Build 15A5209g)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remember to delete all simulators and restart the computer?

Comment: No I didn't but just remedied that..deleted all simulators, them added a new simulator iPhone Xs, but get the same result...

Comment: Delete the app and restart the simulator. Try running 3-4 times. It worked for me. when it takes too long to run an app, this error occurs.

Comment: I just waited until beta 6 came out and it works fine....